# mysql to Elasticsearch : group by and order by use selected field

Tags: elasticsearch

```sql
select count(*) as count, (timestamp div 10) as time from table group by time order by time;
```

How to translate to Elasticsearch or use other es function to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try below query:**

```
GET <indexName>/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "RESULTS": {
      "terms": {
        "script": {
          "source": "doc['timestamp'].value.getMillis()/10"
        },
        "order": {
          "_term": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do the same without any script query.
Syntax can change depending on your elasticsearch version.

```
GET {index}/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "date_count": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "fixed_interval": "10ms",
        "order": {
          "_key": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's strange that not work as I thought.  My `timestamp ` value like `1568867194`. I have 2 days data , set `fixed_interval` as `1h` , only get one agg result .